# Multiple cookies with same name after changing the sameSite setting

Tags: node.js, session-cookies

Context:
In our Node.js & express based app I updated the cookie settings from

```js
res.cookie(newCookieName, sessionCookie, {
    domain: getCookiesDomain(),
    maxAge: ms('30 days'),
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true
});
```

To this slightly different options by adding explicitly `sameSite` property:

```js
res.cookie(newCookieName, sessionCookie, {
    domain: getCookiesDomain(),
    maxAge: ms('30 days'),
    secure: true,
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'lax'
});
```

And as result, I see 2 values of cookies stored at browser, probably due different `sameSite` values ("default" and explicitly set `lax` value).

Browser: Chrome 102, OS: Windows 11.

Who else experienced this double-cookies at case of updated cookie settings?

**Update**

Possible cause is that at least Chrome (or may be other browsers as well?) threat different configuration of these flags and options like `HttpOnly`, `Secure` or `SameSite` as part of cookie full identity, among with origin and name of cookie.

It is possible to mitigate this problem by these tactics:

1. if you use some different format in new version of cookie, like `s:value.signature` in old cookie and `prefix.JWT_base64url` you will have to scan all arriving cookie values by parsing manually arriving `Cookie` header to be able detect this case. Standard Express cookie parsing code for `express-session` useless in this tricky scenario.
2. The second part is to clear manually cookies with deprecated/legacy options like `Secure`, `HttpOnly` and absent or different `SameSite` values. So if you did not specify `SameSite`, than later used `Lax` value and finally settled on `Strict` value, you will have 3 separate cookies, so you will need 2 cookie cleanup commands (2 additional `set-cookie` headers) set with response to clear these old versions of cookies.

Of course you can add custom properties to `Request` in express to mark request with flags mentioning whether such extra headers should be sent with response for request where multi-cookie issue was detected to send extra cleanup `set-cookie` headers with empty value and negative `maxAge` in `res.cookie` cleanup call only when such custom flags present on request, if you use this tweak.

Note that standard `res.clearCookie` provided by Express unaware of this issue and you can not provide the related options there, as I know.

Comment: Having a list of people who experienced doesn't seem terribly useful. If you want to ask for *why that happens* or *how to fix it* (you probably have to specify what the intended result is) then you should ask about that.

Comment: I just was so puzzled after facing that problem that I sorta considered this some unique bug, and assumed that if anyone else faced that, they are probably got an idea for a solution

Comment: Then what you need to ask about is a solution. The question should be clear if it is to be useful. "Who experienced X" is not asking for a solution. Nor for anything explicit.

Comment: Added a workaround for that issue.